# Bloomberg Anywhere and BLPAPI

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

I successfully developed an application through BLPAPI (Bloomberg API) on a Bloomberg Terminal machine (in Python). Unfortunately my company is thinking to switch to Bloomberg Anywhere...I will have the chance to run my application there?

Comment: As long as you are logged in on the machine it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

With a move to Bloomberg Anywhere from open Bloomberg, you will have the same access to data that you had before.  However, you will need to keep the following in mind:

1. Authentication will be linked to an individual person instead of a   Username/Password.   This means that the person who owns the Bloomberg login will need to be physically present at the machine to login using their fingerprint on the Bloomberg keyboard, a b-unit, or our newly released b-unit mobile app (for recent versions of android).
2. Your app will no longer be limited to running on the current machine only.  You will now be able to install a Bloomberg access point and use your application on any windows machine as long as you have the person present as described above to log into the box.
3. Once logged in you will have data access for a few days, however if the Bloomberg anywhere user logs in to Bloomberg on a separate machine, then the machine with your python application will immediately lose access to data.   To regain access, the Bloomberg anywhere user will have to re-login to the original machine.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just be sure that the user logs in every so often. The API will work when a user is connected and even after they disconnect, for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work fine, we've done some applications under BBanywhere.

The only issue I've seen which you should contemplate before going live application is ensuring that if you're moving it off the main box and it's a non-technical party using the service on a laptop or something, that the appropriate python install and dependencies are set up (ie. conda, blpapi, etc.) I've seen some people comfortable enough to run the script or app, then run on laptop or other computer under anywhere all of a sudden that doesn't work because the dependencies aren't there.